# Is there a way to increment counter in prometheus for similar metrics scraped from pushgateway

Tags: c#, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, metrics

I have a running instance of pushgateway and prometheus. And prometheus is configured to scrape from pushgateway. I am able to push metrics from my .NET applications to pushgateway which are successfully scraped by my prometheus. But when a two similar metrics are pushed to pushgateway, they are considered as one by the prometheus and the count is always displayed as one. Is there a way to increment the prometheus count value when similar metrics are present in the pushgateway.

Answer (score 3):

Pushgateway is not designed to handle this situation. As the official doc said, `Usually, the only valid use case for the Pushgateway is for capturing the outcome of a service-level batch job.`

https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/#should-i-be-using-the-pushgateway

Or you can use this instead, which is a aggregating push gateway for Prometheus: https://github.com/weaveworks/prom-aggregation-gateway

Answer (score 1):

The metrics from the two apps should be separated by adding a label that will distinguish between them. This should solve your issue.
Note that the pushgateway [docs](https://gitlab.cncf.ci/prometheus/pushgateway#about-metric-inconsistencies) explicitly state that there should be no duplicate metrics.

Comment: I don't want them to be considered different. My actual use case is to increment the count when similar metrics are being scraped from prometheus

Comment: In that case you should push 2 different metrics to pushgateway, and sum them together when you query them, across the different labels. I'll add a reference to my original answer.